# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I dont know what to do here. When i try rake db:migrate. I get this below

```
$ rake db:migrate 
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
== 20150329164142 CreateCarts: migrating     ======================================
-- create_table(:carts)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "carts" already exists: CREATE TABLE "carts" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AU
TOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL) c:/Work/depot/db
/migrate/20150329164142_create_carts.rb:3:in `change'
c:in `migrate'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table "carts" already exists: CREATE TABLE "carts" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
c:/Work/depot/db/migrate/20150329164142_create_carts.rb:3:in `change'
c:in `migrate'
SQLite3::SQLException: table "carts" already exists
c:/Work/depot/db/migrate/20150329164142_create_carts.rb:3:in `change'
c:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am really new to programming in general and I have tried the `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` and `rake db:rollback`. nothing seems to work. I tried deleting the carts folders and starting the generate scaffold process again and the migrations is still a problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to create a table `carts` that already exists.
One way to resolve this problem is to create a new migration that takes care of deleting the table then I would run a new migration to create the `carts` table.

So first, `rails g migration drop_table_carts`

```
class DropTableCarts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      drop_table :carts  
    end
end
```

Then run a new migration `rails generate migration create_table_carts <column_name>:<column_type>`

Check out your migration folder you should see a create_carts migration file:

```
class CreateCarts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :carts do |t|
    end
  end
end
```

finally, `rake db:migrate`. And voila! That should take care of your problem